# How to get indices of values of numpy array which are zero

Tags: python, numpy

Lets say I have a numpy array as below:

```
array([ 1. ,  2. ,  0. ,  3.4,  0. ,  1.1])
```

Now I want to get indices of all the elements which are zero. Reason being I want to get those indices and then for a different array I want to convert the elements on same indices to zero.

To get indices of non zero I know we can use nonzero or argwhere.

```
np.nonzero(a)

(array([0, 1, 3, 5]),)
```

Then lets say I have array b I can use the above indices list and convert all the elements of array b with same indices to zero like below:

```
b[np.nonzero(a)]=0
```

This is fine but it is for non zero indices. How to get for zero indices.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to use the result for indexing purposes, it's more efficient to make a boolean array than an array of indices:

```
a == 0
```

You can index with that the same way you would have used the array of indices:

```
b[a == 0] = 0
```

If you really want an array of indices, you can call `np.nonzero` on the boolean array:

```
np.nonzero(a == 0)
```

`np.where` also works.